# StringBuilder.append() causes java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stringbuilder

I'm experiencing a strange issue using the `append()` method of `StringBuilder` class; here is the method:

```
public StringBuilder toStringBuilder(byte[] b)
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) 
        {
            s.append(Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100,16).substring(1));
        }
    System.out.println(s);
    return s;
}
```

It takes a byte array and converts it into a `StringBuilder` (doing other stuff in the meanwhile).

Everything seems OK, when I run the program it prints the correct result, but shows also a `NullPointerException` that doesn't let me continue using the program; the exception is pointed to the fourth line

```
(for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++))
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Only thing that can be null in that place is `b`. Check the callers of the method...

Comment: b is not null... here's the call: 
String out[] = new String[2]; 
out[0] = toStringBuilder(message).toString(); 
where message is a byte array of 16 elements; here's a print:
4
-52
81
-122
26
-28
110
-74
-112
51
-103
0
4
122
4
117

Comment: @tenik The error in your stack trace is on line 165: `for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)` ==> `b` is null.

Comment: you are passing `message` to `b`. Here, `message` is `null`, causing `b` to be `null`.

Comment: well... it doesn't seem to be null

[link](http://i39.tinypic.com/4zybdx.png)

Comment: include this code at the beginning of your method: `if (b == null) { System.out.println("b is null"); }`

Comment: Maybe you called `toStringBuilder` twice and the second time failed.

Comment: @tenik - I don't think the additional linked screenshot says anything relevant to the null-ness of `b`.

Comment: Please don't use an image of the code/stack trace when you could just paste the text into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
```

throws an NPE, there is only one possible explanation.  `b` is `null`.

You can prove (or disprove) this by adding this statement immediately before the `for` statement.

```
System.out.println("b is " + b);
```

Once you've confirmed that, you need to work backwards to figure out why the `b` is `null` at that point.  I can't offer any insights based on the code you've shown us.

Answer (score 0):

its working correctly in my code , check b before processing it for null.

```
if(b!=null)
{
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) 
        {
            s.append(Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100,16).substring(1));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding () brackets after length like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) 
        {
```